# Getting element position scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a one page layout where I want to show few elements on window scrollTop, but I have problem with calculating the Element position. 
Here are the things I'm doing but I'm getting my scrollTop in Negative values and I have no idea why.

```js
var myEl = $('.myElement').offset().top; 
var currPos = ( myEl - $(window).scrollTop() ); 


$(window).scroll(function(){
   var wScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   
   if (wScrollTop > currPos) {
    alert("reached");
    myEl.fadeIn(2000);
   }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 3000px;
}

.myElement {
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>Some othe content</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
      
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto ullam minima, veniam, maiores molestiae assumenda pariatur corrupti voluptatum id ea commodi aperiam dignissimos fuga, exercitationem illo eius praesentium suscipit. Velit.</p>

<div class="myElement">My Element</div>
```

I want to run this code only once not like on my example few time alerting that the position is reached. Also Im not sure about calculating the currPos of my element. Any suggestions which is the best way how to calculate current Position of the element and then on window scroll top showing only once my desired element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is updated script.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var myEl = jQuery('.myElement');
    var myElem = myEl.offset().top-100;
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var wScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

       if (wScrollTop > myElem) {
        myEl.fadeIn(2000);
      } else {
        myEl.fadeOut(2000);
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: thats good one but is there any way to get bottom of the window scroll ? The idea is to show the effect when bottom of the window is scrolled to this Element because if top it is scrolled is showing it too late ? @Ankit